# Перевод числа в строку без встроенных функций

Tags: c++, строки

Как данную функцию реализовать базовыми методами, без использования встроенных функций.

```
string str = to_string(i);
```

i - число от 2 до 99

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например, так:

```
string s("");
if (i >= 10) s += '0' + i/10;
s += '0' + i%10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  int i = 5;
  string str;
  stringstream ss;
  ss << i;
  str = ss.str();
```